# Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>. Next JS error

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm creating a whatsapp clone using next.js. On the first load of app i'm getting this error.

```
  Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>.
    at div
    at O (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1621219033615:37232:19450)
    at div
    at Paper (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/chat.js?ts=1621219033615:45091:23)
    at WithStyles (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/chat.js?ts=1621219033615:64751:31)
    at div
    at Drawer (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/chat.js?ts=1621219033615:33839:29)
    at WithStyles (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/chat.js?ts=1621219033615:64751:31)
    at SideBar (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/chat.js?ts=1621219033615:67329:75)
    at div
    at O (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1621219033615:37232:19450)
    at Chat (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/chat.js?ts=1621219033615:73282:70)
    at SideMenuProvider (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1621219033615:25916:23)
    at MyApp (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/pages/_app.js?ts=1621219033615:31532:24)
    at ErrorBoundary (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1621219033615:726:47)
    at ReactDevOverlay (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1621219033615:829:23)
    at Container (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1621219033615:8388:5)
    at AppContainer (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1621219033615:8876:24)
    at Root (http://localhost:3000/_next/static/chunks/main.js?ts=1621219033615:9012:25)
```

I'm totally unaware of the source of this error. and they also did not specified from which file, the error is occurred.

Because of this error App UI gets shatter from this
[Actual UI of APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79z45.png)
to this
[Errored UI of APP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLMls.png)

If anybody have any idea why this is happening please help me.

_document.js code here

```js
import React from "react";
import Document, { Html, Main, NextScript, Head } from "next/document";
import { ServerStyleSheets } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html lang="en">
        <Head>
          {/* Meta Tags for SEO */}
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Comatible" content="IE=edge" />
          <meta
            name="description"
            content="A WhatsApp clone made using next js and firebase."
          />
          <meta name="keywords" content="WhatsApp Clone" />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async (ctx) => {
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    styles: [
      ...React.Children.toArray(initialProps.styles),
      sheets.getStyleElement(),
    ],
  };
};
```

Comment: That happens because the HTML generated on the server doesn't match what's initially rendered in the client. Do you use any component library by any chance?

Comment: @juliomalves Yes. I'm using Material UI and Styled Components. If have any idea how to fix, pls tell me.

Comment: What does your `_document` look like? Did you setup SSR correctly for those? Check out [Next.js with Material UI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/nextjs/pages/_document.js) and [styled-components with Next.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/master/examples/with-styled-components/pages/_document.js).

Comment: you can see the code above _document.js. I copy pasted that repo code in my code already.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to import your components dynamically:

```js
const MyDynamicComponent = dynamic(() => import('./myComponent'))
```